# COUNTA with FILTER function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to count the percentage of fully filled cells in an excel sheet. I do that by counting the filled cells in a column combining FILTER, CHOOSECOLS and COUNTA functions and then divide by total of cells.

My formula works if my cells are full but always returns 1 if the cells are empty.
Is there any way to count the cells ?

Many thanks,

Here is the formula with `COUNTA` :

```
=COUNTA(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Table4,("XX" = Table4[XX])*("XX" = Table4[XX])*(0 <> Table4[XX)])),4)) / COUNTA(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Table4,("XX" = Table4[BU])*("Critical" = Table4[XX])),4))
```

I tried using `COUNT` and `IF` instead but no success.

```
=COUNT(IF(IFERROR(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Table4,("XX" = Table4[XX])*("XX" = Table4[XX])*(0 <> Table4[XX]),0),14),0)= "0",0,"")) / COUNTA(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Table4,("XX" = Table4[XX])*("XX" = Table4[XX])),4))
```

Comment: Instead of using `COUNTA()` use `SUM()` --> `SUM(--(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Table4,("XX" = Table4[XX])*("XX" = Table4[XX])*(0 <> Table4[XX)]),""),4))<>""))/SUM(--(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Table4,("XX" = Table4[BU])*("Critical" = Table4[XX]),""),4)<>""))`

Comment: I have a #VALUE! error when I run this

Comment: Sorry cant say without any example posted in the OP. Btw that should work, tried on my end with the given idea

Comment: If I copy paste your formula directly, I have the Excel popup "there is a probleme with this formula", I'm not familiar with SUM function so I think its from my side

Comment: The possible reason is I missed one of the parentheses could be, and as I have said, the following formula should work.

Comment: This would be the correct formula with all the details : =SUM(--(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Table4,("ERCZ" = Table4[BU])*("Critical" = Table4[Criticity level])*(0 <> Table4[Internal(information available in FA))]),""),4))<>""))/SUM(--(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Table4,("ERCZ" = Table4[BU])*("Critical" = Table4[Criticity level]),""),4)<>"")) --> I get the popup error

Comment: Try now: `=SUM(--(IFERROR(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Table4,("ERCZ" = Table4[BU])*("Critical" = Table4[Criticity level])*(0 <> Table4[Internal(information available in FA)]),""),4),"")<>""))/SUM(--(IFERROR(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Table4,("ERCZ" = Table4[BU])*("Critical" = Table4[Criticity level]),""),4),"")<>""))`

Comment: Filter returns a value, in case you filtered out all values it returns an error ( `=FILTER({1,2,3},{1,2,3}>4)` returns `#CALC!` or `=FILTER({1,2,3},{1,2,3}>4,"")` returns a blank value. Both situations return 1 in `COUNTA()`). The condition used to filter can be used as boolean in sum (make sure to convert the boolean to numerical representation: `=SUM(N({1,2,3}>4))`